# C# Localized Resources.resx doesn't allow for other languages

Tags: c#, winforms

Good evening,

I happen to have an issue with Winforms and Resources.resx.

The app I'm working on is built via 'Winforms App' template selectable via Visual Studio.
The issue I'm having is kind of outside of winforms localization - which I think is important to mention.

Here's my issue:
 - I've created a 'HistoryManager' class, which has only one method and one action to perform - add a history to the SQL database.
 - I've created Resource.resx file, entered a format string into it under "MsgTaskAdded" which is equal to "Task {0} has been added to {1}".
 - The said string adds to the database flawlessly.

`Resources.resx` works well - if I change `MsgTaskAdded` resource string, it changes what will be added to database .

Now, the issue I'm having is.
 - I've created a `Resources.de-DE.resx` file, copied strings from `Resources.resx` and translated to german.
 - Changed `CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` to 'de-DE'.
As a result, the text added to database is STILL in english, as if the file wasn't found and it fell back into using the default `Resources.resx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

If you guys ever have issue with the `Resources.resx`, make sure the localized file isn't: `Resources.de-DE.resx` or `Resources.pl-PL.resx`, instead - use only the first bit (Resources.de.resx) and make sure to open the file and set accessors to 'Internal' so it generates you a Designer file with proper code.

Answer (score 1):

Make certain that your `Resources.de-DE.resx` file is contained within the Properties folder of your project, and that it has a Build Action of `Embedded Resource`, so that it gets properly associated to your default `Resources.resx` during compile. The culture settings on `CurrentThread` also need to happen before the call to the database, ideally somewhere in your `static void Main()` function before the `Application.Run(…)` call.

This should produce a culture-specific folder in your `bin\<build_configuration>` folder that contains a file named `<your_app>.resources.dll`. If needed, you can crack this open with a tool like ILSpy or Reflector to verify that the translated resources exist in the expected place within the assembly.

Comment: Both: `Resources.resx` and `Resources.de-DE.resx` have Build Action set to Embedded Resource, there's also a 'de-DE' folder that contains file called `LibraryTracker.resources.dll` - LibraryTracker being my namespace.

The setting of culture is also ran in the first 2 lines of Main.

I'll try cracking it open tho and let you know - I also appreciate the help.

Comment: It seems that the resource compiled properly - I can see my resource in there. What else could be breaking, if the resource compiles properly?

Comment: Not sure where else the problem might lie, but I posted the little sample app I wrote to [my GitHub](https://github.com/BrandonSharp/SO---Sample-WinForms-Localization) if you wanted to take a look to see where a difference between mine and yours might exist. There's a button on Form1 that pops a message box with the localized string. Hope that helps!

Comment: I've replicated your code in my project, but it doesn't seem to work.

The whole project is rather robust, in fact it's a legacy code solution with roughly 7 projects attached to it.

I'm clueless at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason in that how you're changing the thread culture. I did exectly what you did and its worked. That is how I've changed the culture

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
   Console.WriteLine(Resources.Hello);
}
```

it prints "Hallo"

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, because I do exactly as these 2 lines say, the same exact code (except for System.Globalization because I've put it in `using`)